# Get the XY coordinates of a buttonfield in Blackberry's main screen

Tags: blackberry, field, coordinate-transformation

I have a lots of content and all content like `Labelfield` `Buttonfield`, `Bitmapfield` and so on.

All these content add in  `MainScreen` .

I want to get the particular `Buttonfield` XY position  from this screen.
I have already tried `buttonField.getContentTop();`, but I'm getting 0.

So, how can I get the XY coordinates of a buttonfield in Blackberry's main screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class sample extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
    ButtonField click;
    LabelField x,y;
    public sample()
    {  

    x=new LabelField("Left(x) position: ");
    add(x);
    y=new LabelField("right(y) position: ");
    add(y);
    click=new ButtonField("Get My Positions",Field.FOCUSABLE);
    click.setChangeListener(this);
    add(click);
    }
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        System.out.println("============================"+click.getLeft()+"     "+click.getTop());
        x.setText("Left(x) position: "+click.getLeft());
        y.setText("right(y) position: "+click.getTop());
    }

}
```